# How to make AsyncTask modular in android

Tags: android

I am quite new to Android Development. I am working in a app where i need to make a lot of async calls to api. For each and every API call, I have to write the similar looking AsyncTask class over and over again. So, is there any way to make these Async Calls modular?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yes it is possible use Listener and AsyncTask with parameterized constructor

Check it

Create an interface

```
public interface OnTaskCompletListerner {
 void oncompleteListerner(String name);
}
```

create an AsyncTask class as follows

```
public class AsyncTaskModuler  extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private Context context;
    private HashMap<String, String> data;
    private String URL;
    private OnTaskCompletListerner taskdone;

    public AsyncTaskModuler(Context ctx,HashMap<String, String> data,String url,OnTaskCompletListerner taskdone){

        this.context=ctx;
        this.data=data;
        this.URL=url;
        this.taskdone=taskdone;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //Do the task here and return the value if needed 
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        taskdone.oncompleteListerner(result);
    }
```

and call it in your activity like this

```
public class CallAync extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String url="";
        HashMap<String, String> data=new HashMap<String, String>();
        AsyncTaskModuler moduler=new AsyncTaskModuler(CallAync.this, data, url, completListerner);
        moduler.execute();
    }

    OnTaskCompletListerner completListerner=new OnTaskCompletListerner() {

        @Override
        public void oncompleteListerner(String name) {

        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I guess this code does the trick. I am trying it. As I am new to android development, can you tell me what would be "Context" useful for??

Comment: Ya u can show the progress bar by passing the context to it '@MilanMaharjan'

Comment: thank you so much... I am accepting your answer, wish i could vote up your answer too, but i dont have the required 15 reputations :(

Answer (score 1):

Create an general async task and pass your url as param to it .Hence you can reuse the same async task for all your api calls

```
public class myTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String muUrl;   


    public myTask(Context context, Activity activity,
            String url) {
        contxt = context;
        myUrl=url;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        makeApiCalls();

        return null;
    }
}
```

**Start the task in the following way :**

```
new myTask(this, this, urlStr).execute();
```

**EDIT**

> How can I perform different logic onPostExecute() ?

You can add another param in the constructor of myTask. 
Ex.

```
    public MyTask(Context context, Activity activity,
                    String url,String postExecuteAction) {
}
```

In your post executes just check of each case in if else and perform the respective task

Comment: how can i execute different logic in onPostExecute() method for each different api calls?

Comment: @Milan set some enum value for the different api calls and check with the enum for the api in postExecute().

Comment: @RachitaNanda if i add respective task in onPostExecute() method, i think the general class wont be modular.

Answer (score 0):

### Dummy Background class

```
 private class BackGroundClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> //<arg to do InBackground,,returntype of do inBackground and arg of onPostExecut>
   
{

 public BackGroundClass()
    {

    }

 @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() //forground work in UI thread prior to doInbackground
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
      
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) //background work in parallel thread
    {
        Bitmap b=null;
       // your background work
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) //forground work in UI thread post to doInbackground
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(result!=null)
        {               
            //use bitmap image in result    
        }
       else
       {   
          //Image is not available
       }    

    }

  }
```

### Calling for one parellel execution

```
new BackGroundClass().execute(StringArg1,stringArg2,StringArg3);
```

### Calling for multiple parellel execution

when tou need to call more than one background task at same time

```
new BackGroundClass().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,StringArg1,stringArg2,StringArg3);
```

### Called from single activity

use this as an inner class to your activity for making it easy to share variable if not called from more than one activity

### Called from more than one activity

use constructor to pass activity context,and other variable

```
new BackGroundClass(constructor arguments).execute(StringArg1,stringArg2,StringArg3);

  new BackGroundClass(constructor arguments).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,StringArg1,stringArg2,StringArg3);
```