# How to throw exception from AsyncTask and handle it outside

Tags: android, exception, android-asynctask

During my implantation I need to throw several exceptions from a class, and handle them outside.
Inside the class I made, I also implemented AsyncTask private class, and from this class , as well, I need to throw the exceptions.
I realized that I cannot throw any exception from AsyncTask class, but only to handle it. This is not what I need.

Is there some kind of solution, so I'll be able to throw any exception I want from inside the AsyncTask?

Comment: you can use your own listener for that

Comment: or could return a object with the information you need. e.g. `String result; String error;` or sth like this.

Comment: @SainathPatwarykarnate Can you please explain how to use listener here?

Comment: @A.S. the only problem is that if I'll return an object, I'll need to wait for the task to end, and I'll loose the asynchronous of the AsyncTask. I do need it to run in the background.

Comment: check the ans http://stackoverflow.com/a/23534743/2751529 which is used to pass the result same way you can pass the Exception object as a result hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

I do something like below.
- Write your own implementation of MyListener class.Pass it in the constructor of MyAsyncTask class.
- Check the return value of doInBackground method,and call relevant method.

```
public interface MyListener {
    public void onSuccess();
    public abstract void onFail();
}

public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{  
    private MyListener listener;  
    public MyAsyncTask(MyListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
}

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return aValue;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String aValue) {
        //Check aValue,if OK
        listener.onSuccess();
        //else
        listener.onFail();
    }
}
```