# how to send arraylist elements from asynctask to activity through listener interface?

Tags: android, bundle, message

Hai am trying to send list elements to the another activity through asynctask but i cant get the proper result can you please help me..

this is my asnctask :

public class AsyncClass extends AsyncTask {

```
Context ct;

ArrayList<GetterSetterClass> listshows;
private String TAG = "AsynClass";
GetterSetterClass gettersettercls;
MainActivity mainActivity;

// Communication between asynclass and mainactivity

public AsyncClass(MainActivity mainActivity) {
    this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
}

public interface ListenerClass {
    public void callbackMyActivity();

}

// Get the Url response from this method

public String queryRESTurl(String urlString) {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpGet = new HttpPost(urlString);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
        } else {
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        Log.i("QueryResult", builder.toString());
    return builder.toString();

}

public JSONObject convertStringtoJsonObject(String result) {
    JSONObject jArray = null;

    try {

        jArray = new JSONObject(result);
    } catch (JSONException e) {

    }

    return jArray;

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        Log.i("EnterDoinbackground", "EnterDoinbackground");
    try {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.i("ShowsUrl", params[0]);
        String results = queryRESTurl(params[0]);

        if (results != null) {

            JSONObject json = convertStringtoJsonObject(results);
            try {

                listshows = new ArrayList<GetterSetterClass>();
                JSONObject result = json
                        .getJSONObject(MainActivity.Rootnode);

                Log.d("Get the string results", "" + result);

                JSONArray jarray = result.getJSONArray(MainActivity.shows);
                int jasonarrayLength = jarray.length();

                for (int i = 0; i < jasonarrayLength; i++) {

                    JSONObject jsonkey = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    gettersettercls = new GetterSetterClass(

                    jsonkey.getString(MainActivity.DATE_CREATED),
                            jsonkey.getString(MainActivity.SHOW_NAME),
                            jsonkey.getString(MainActivity.PLAY_NAME),
                            jsonkey.getString(MainActivity.SHOW_COVER),
                            jsonkey.getInt(MainActivity.ASSET_COUNT),
                            jsonkey.getInt(MainActivity.SHOW_ID),
                            jsonkey.getString(MainActivity.LINK_MD5),
                            jsonkey.getString(MainActivity.DESCRIPTION));
                    listshows.add(gettersettercls);

                    /*
                     * Log.i("list elements", "List elements displayed :\n"
                     * + listshows);
                     */
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Exception thrown :" + e);
            }
        } else {

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Log.i("Listitems", "" + listshows.size());

    Message msg = Message.obtain();
    msg.obj = listshows;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.sendMessage(msg);

    if (!mainActivity.isFinishing()) {

        mainActivity.callbackMyActivity();

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Hope this link may help you , change  this String to Array list it will as per your expectations.

[How to make AsyncTask modular in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23534418/how-to-make-asynctask-modular-in-android/23534743#23534743)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get data from an ASyncTask is by implementing a callback.

Create an Interface:

```
public interface OnRESTCallFinishedListener {
  public void onDataReady(ArrayList<GetterSetterClass> listshows);
}
```

In you AsyncClass:

```
private OnRESTCallFinishedListener listener;

public void setOnRESTCallFinishedListener(OnRESTCallFinishedListener listener){
  this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<GetterSetterClass> result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    listener.onDataReady(result);
}
```

In your Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnRESTCallFinishedListener {
```

and override onDataReady:

```
@override
public void onDataReady(ArrayList<GetterSetterClass> listshows){
   //display your data.
}
```

Make sure that when you create your AsyncTask instance in your activity you set the listener otherwise this will not work:

```
AsyncClass dataLoader = new AsyncClass();
dataLoader.setOnRESTCallFinishedListener(this);
```